# How to make a screenshot with changed render logical size in SDL?

Tags: c++, screenshot, sdl-2

You can set rendering resolution independently from window/fullscreen size with SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize, but all the methods of taking a screenshot gave either a black image, an image with exactly how it looks on screen (even with outside overlays, like RivaTuner Statistics Server), or the same, squished into left-upper corner of the screen. All screenshot are having window resolution instead of set rendering resolution. How to save a copy of viewport fresh after rendering into a file, so it would have set rendering resolution and won't have outside overlays?

Comment: Does [`SDL_RenderReadPixels()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderReadPixels) work?

Comment: @genpfault it produces the squished inside a corner image (since I pass logical size as width and height), screenshot's resolution is still 1920x1080

Comment: Logical size only used to transform coordinates you pass. After rasterisation it no longer exists. What result do you expect (and why you need it)? You can transform window coordinates to logical via simple scale if you have to.